# Should the summation symbol be used for Ramanujan Summation?

Tags: discussion

I recently asked a [question about Ramanujan Summation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2861517/how-do-i-derive-the-ramanujan-summation-of-sum-n-1-inftyn2-0), and naturally some confusion over what I was asking arose. Should we use $\sum$ for irregular summations such as Ramanujan Summation? Or should we agree on some other symbol like $R^{\infty}_{j=1}$? Or am I just overthinking this?

Comment: The symbols used are not particularly important. What is important is to make sure everything is clearly stated and described within the text itself. In your question, I think it's very clear. If you decide to use some other symbol, then make that symbol's usage clear and there is no problem. However I think it is folly to try to get many to agree on some other symbol for general use, especially as mathematicians have talked about diverging sums for over a century.

Comment: The wiki entry put a $(\Re)$ on the left to indicate it is a Ramanujan sum.
eg. $$1 + 2 + 3 + \cdots = -\frac{1}{12}\;\;(\Re)$$ I think this a reasonable alternative than using a new symbol for summation.

Comment: It is not up to this website to introduce new standard notation. Moreover, writing anything other than "... here the summation is in the sense of Ramanujan" (or something equivalent) is bound to incur additional questions about the notation. So it's just simpler, quicker, and faster, to write just that.

Comment: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n\ {{\cal R}\atop=}\ -{1\over12}$$ only there's probably some clever way to bring the $\cal R$ and the $=$ closer together.

Comment: @GerryMyerson As a minor followup, here is a clever way to bring the $\mathcal{R}$ closer to the $=$ sign. $$ \sum_{n = 1}^\infty n\stackrel{\mathcal{R}}{=} - \frac{1}{12}$$

Comment: @david, that looks much better. Good old \stackrel!

Comment: Although the topic here is narrow and perhaps even (mildly) contentious, issues of "good use of notation" seem to me worthy of discussion on Meta Math.SE, as part of our curation of excellent content.

Answer (score 9):

You're *underthinking* this: the problem is

> The reader doesn't understand what is meant.

While using $\Sigma$ introduces confusion because the reader expects it to mean the limit of partial sums, switching to a new symbol like $R$ introduces confusion because the reader has never seen it before and has no clue what you might mean!

You need another approach to solve the actual problem. The most obvious is to say up front, in *words*, that your post is not discussing the usual notion of summation, and is instead using Ramanujan's method. Or if not up front, to say it when a summation first appears in your post.

IMO it's not enough to simply say "this is a Ramanujan sum"; readers who don't know what that means are likely to think that a "Ramanujan sum" is just a funny name for certain ordinary infinite sums, sort of like how we call $\Sigma x^n$ a "geometric series".

If your post only considers Ramanujan summation, then using $\Sigma$ to denote it is reasonable, and maybe $\ldots$ based alternatives are reasonable as well.

If both Ramanujan summation and the usual notion of infinite summation appear in your post, then you will have a need to distinguish between them; a new symbol or decoration would be a reasonable way to do this.

Comment: Ironic that you used the wrong symbol too: it's `\sum` ($\sum$), not `\Sigma` ($\Sigma$) :-)

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform: It was intentional; I was optimizing for English text, not mathematical formulae, and `\Sigma` inlines better.